# Finding identical keys in multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have an object with the rough following structure. I need to find if one email exists in another object (month) and if it does, in which one. Ideally I would be able to look at all the months in which the user belongs too so I can then say something like "hello@gmail.com is active in September and October". I'm a little familiar with Underscore so I could use that.

How can I create a new object with the email addresses as unique keys with an array of all the dates that email occurred in?

```
data: Object {
  2015-08-09: Object {
    hello@gmail.com: 5,
    hello2@gmail.com: 4,
    hello4@gmail.com: 6
  }

  2015-09-09: Object {
    hello@gmail.com: 5,
    hello2@gmail.com: 4,
    hello4@gmail.com: 6,
    hello9@gmail.com: 4
  }

  2015-10-09: Object {
    hello@gmail.com: 5,
    hello2@gmail.com: 4,
    hello4@gmail.com: 6,
    hello9@gmail.com: 10,
    hello5@gmail.com: 7
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for ... in` loop to loop through the object, and build a new object from the original.

```js
function flipObj( i ) {
  
  // If the input variable is not an object, fail.
  if( typeof i !== "object" ) return false;

  // If the input object is empty, fail
  if( Object.keys( i ).length === 0 ) return false;
  
  // Create an empty object.
  o = {};

  // Loop through the dates
  for( var d in i ) {
    
    // If the property in question is not an object, skip it.
    if( typeof i[d] !== "object" ) continue;
    
    // If the property is empty, skip it.
    if( Object.keys( i[d] ).length === 0 ) continue;

    // Loop through the email addresses
    for( var e in i[d] ) {

      // If there is no property in our created object for the email, make one
      if(!o[e]) o[e] = { days: [], id: i[d][e] };
      
      // Push the day into the days array for the email object in question.
      o[e].days.push( d );

    }
  }

  // If our new object is empty, fail
  if( Object.keys( o ).length === 0 ) return false;

  // Return our new object.
  return o;
}

// Works
console.log( flipObj( { '2015-08-09': { 'hello@gmail.com': 5, 'hello2@gmail.com': 4, 'hello4@gmail.com': 6 }, '2015-09-09': { 'hello@gmail.com': 5, 'hello2@gmail.com': 4, 'hello4@gmail.com': 6, 'hello9@gmail.com': 4 }, '2015-10-09': { 'hello@gmail.com': 5, 'hello2@gmail.com': 4, 'hello4@gmail.com': 6, 'hello9@gmail.com': 10, 'hello5@gmail.com': 7 } } ) ); 
// Fails
console.log( flipObj( {} ) ); 
// Fails
console.log( flipObj( { 'hello': 'world' } ) );
```

The following is the output from the above script

```js
[object Object] {
  hello2@gmail.com: [object Object] {
    days: ["2015-08-09", "2015-09-09", "2015-10-09"],
    id: 4
  },
  hello4@gmail.com: [object Object] {
    days: ["2015-08-09", "2015-09-09", "2015-10-09"],
    id: 6
  },
  hello5@gmail.com: [object Object] {
    days: ["2015-10-09"],
    id: 7
  },
  hello9@gmail.com: [object Object] {
    days: ["2015-09-09", "2015-10-09"],
    id: 4
  },
  hello@gmail.com: [object Object] {
    days: ["2015-08-09", "2015-09-09", "2015-10-09"],
    id: 5
  }
}
false
false
```

As you can see we now have an object for each email address containing an array of the days and the id.

Comment: Great! Your code got me pointed in the right direction and I was able to tweak it to do a few extra things. Thanks!